# Integral over a torus - change of variables

Tags: real-analysis, integration, multivariable-calculus

Heyyyy

I would like to understand how to perform the variables change $\phi \rightarrow \psi$ in the following sum

$$
\int_{\varphi \in \mathbb{T}^2} h(\alpha(\varphi),\beta(\varphi)) d\varphi
$$

where $\alpha(\varphi) = \langle \varphi, \omega \rangle,
\beta(\varphi) = \langle \varphi, \omega^{\perp} \rangle$

- One can identify $\mathbb{T}^2$ à $S^1 \times S^1$, so $\varphi = (\varphi_1,\varphi_2)$.
- Then $\psi = (\psi_1,\psi_2) = (\alpha(\varphi),\beta(\varphi))$
  It's a diffeo on the torus: $\varphi \rightarrow \psi = (\varphi_1\omega_1 + \varphi_2\omega_2,-\varphi_1\omega_2 + \varphi_2\omega_1)$.
- $d\psi = (\omega_1 d\varphi_1 + \omega_2 \varphi_2,-\omega_2 d\varphi_1 + \omega_1 \varphi_2) = (\langle d\psi,\omega\rangle, \langle d\psi,\omega^{\perp} \rangle$ ... ?

how to write the new integral ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have that $d \psi = \left( \omega_1^2 + \omega_2^2 \right) d \phi$. Then your integral is just $$\int_{\psi \in S^1 \times S^1} h(\psi_1, \psi_2)\frac{1}{\omega_1^2 + \omega_2^2}d \psi$$